# Make a POST request using Ajax & Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I am following this documentation on how to make a post request using ajax and django:

https://dev.to/coderasha/how-to-send-django-form-with-ajax-4bpo

---

This is how far I got:

---

import.html

```
  <form method="POST" id="solver_args-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

---

```
$(document).on('submit', '#solver_args-form',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{% url "create" %}',
        data:{
            name:$('#id_name').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        success:function(json){
            document.getElementById("solver_args-form").reset();
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); 
    }
    });
});
```

---

views.py

```
def update_solverargs(request):
    solver_args = SolverArgs.objects.all()
    response_data = {}
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    response_data['name']           = name
    SolverArgs.objects.create(
        name = name,
    )
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
return render(request, 'import.html', {'solver_args':solver_args})
```

---

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$', update_solverargs, name='update_solverargs'),
]
```

---

No errors in console, the page does refresh when I submit the form and nothing gets stored into the database.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Required is a separate attribute. When required is present, input field must be filled out before submitting the form. See here: [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) Also : Field.blank
If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.

Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Comment: I see, thank you very much

Comment: I will make this an answer instead of a comment. Please upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
if request.POST.get('action') == 'POST':
```

to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

and now it works !!

Answer (score 0):

`Required` is a separate attribute. When `required` is present, input field must be filled out before submitting the form. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp    Also from Django documentation:

> Field.blank If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is
>   False. Note that this is different than null. null is purely
>   database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has
>   blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a
>   field has blank=False, the field will be required.
>   Blockquote

You will need to specify `blank = True` For example: `field = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='', blank=True)`

Comment: Ive set `blank=True` and `null=True` on the fields of the django model, isn't that the same thing? Also, this is still not working.

Comment: I show the difference between True and null in the answer. I also edited the answer to show this example: `field = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='', blank=True)`

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not about the difference between NULL and BLANK.